# Different Default.png files for different targets in one project

Tags: ios, xcode4

I'm trying to set up a second target in my project, but when I drag the Default*.png files over to the Launch Images section of the target it tells me its going to overwrite the Default.png from my original target.

How do we add different launch images for different targets?

Before you answer, please understand I'm not looking for how to include different general files or images in different targets. I understand that, I'm specifically dealing with a problem regarding the Default.png launch images when I drag them onto the target pane's Launch Images section.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your [info.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html) for each project, you create a entry for [UILaunchImageFile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW24) pointing to the launch image.